# Delete Row data from database table using Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
{
    if (item.Index < rows_count)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        db.COA_LedgerDetails.Remove(cOALedgerDetailsBindingSource.Current as COA_LedgerDetails);
        cOALedgerDetailsBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here is my Code. I added Multiple rows in Datagridview that is saved into database table and if i want to delete Second or third row from table It delete first row everytime.

Comment: you are removing current row. you need to pass the ID (unique id ) to db.COA_LedgerDetails.Remove(uniqueId)

Comment: I have not displayed the ID in Datagridview . I have only displayed other properties. So What should i do now

Comment: You need to have the ID in your grid somewhere. Whether you display it or not is up to you. That's the unique identifier for the record and how the db knows which record to remove.

Comment: Thanks, I added the ID and Now it works Properly

Answer (score 0):

you are removing current row. you need to pass the ID (unique id ) to 
 db.COA_LedgerDetails.Remove(uniqueId)`